# where is the previous data dump of stack overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, data-dump

As far as I know, the previous version of data dump of stackoverflow is on clearbits.net. However, recently, I cannot find them. I even cannot access clearbits website. Right now, I can only find the one on Jan-20-2014 and 09-2013. But where are the others? I once saw a lot on clearbits.

Comment: Clearbits is gone. Long live Clearbits!

Comment: did they delete all the previous versions of data dump? I remember they will dump the data at least twice a year.